# Azure String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, azure

Interestingly, the code below works on our on-premise environment but not in azure web role.

Could someone point me to right direction what I'm doing wrong.

We get date and time as string from third party and use logic below to parse.

```
string givenDate="21/06/2013";
string givenTime="7:35 PM";

var givenDateTime = DateTime.Parse(givenDate + " " + givenTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The above code throws exception below in Azure:

```
Exception: System.FormatException
Message: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: Can you try `ParseExact` instead?

Comment: I don't think there anything to do with Azure - `DateTime.Parse( "21/06/2013 7:35 PM ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` fails anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The invariant culture uses US month/day/year format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

> The "d" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time
>   format string that is defined by a specific culture's
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern property. For example, *the custom
>   format string that is returned by the ShortDatePattern property of the
>   invariant culture is "MM/dd/yyyy".*